# Absence of Consing in SBCL loop

Tags: loops, common-lisp, sbcl

```
* (defparameter lst (make-list 1000))
LST
* (time (loop for x in lst
              for i from 0
              unless (= i 500)
              collect x))
Evaluation took:
  0.000 seconds of real time
  0.000000 seconds of total run time (0.000000 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  47,292 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

How does SBCL build the return list with 0 bytes consed?

Comment: You could try `macroexpand`ing your `loop` form to see what's going on there. 0 count probably refers to *additional* cons cells. CLISP conses them up, and calls `nreverse` in the end.

Comment: The `unless` is a bit useless for the benchmark. If you increase the list size, then the cons counter goes up. Maybe the memory is reclaimed right after the loop finishes when the list is sufficiently small, and somehow in that case does not get counted by `time`. See https://medium.com/@MartinCracauer/llvms-garbage-collection-facilities-and-sbcl-s-generational-gc-a13eedfb1b31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test case is too small for `time`. Try `(defparameter lst 100000)`.

```
Evaluation took:
  0.003 seconds of real time
  0.003150 seconds of total run time (0.002126 user, 0.001024 system)
  100.00% CPU
  8,518,420 processor cycles
  1,579,472 bytes consed
```